# gnuplot epslatex problem

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplottex

I am having a really really weird problem trying to include graphics files in my latex document that were created using the `gnuplot` `epslatex` terminal.

I have created a `gnuplot` script which uses the `epslatex` terminal and writes the output to a file named `foo.tex`. As expected it outputs two files: `foo.eps` and `foo.tex`. In my latex file named `paper.tex` I then include `foo.tex` in a figure by using:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\input{foo.tex}
\end{figure}
```

I then compile the latex file using the command:

```
  latex paper.tex
```

I then convert the `paper.dvi` file to a `.ps` file using:

```
  dvips paper.dvi
```

and I then try to convert this to a `.pdf` file using:

```
  ps2pdf paper.ps
```

but it fails with an error message that means just about nothing to me and I can't view the plot in the `.pdf` file when using my `.pdf` viewer. Here is the error message:

```
    Error: /syntaxerror in /--%ztokenexec_continue--
    Operand stack:
    ExtendTextBox
    Execution stack:
    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval-- --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   1   3   %oparray_pop   2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   2025   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
    Dictionary stack:
    --dict:960/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:90/200(L)--   --dict:198/300(L)--   --dict:67/200(L)--   --dict:181/256(L)--
    Current allocation mode is local
    GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Now here's the really really weird part. After much frustration (many hours) I accidentally found that if I run my `gnuplot` script but write to the screen (that is I comment out the part that sets the terminal to `epslatex` and I comment out the part that writes the output to a file) and then I retry the `ps2pdf` command it then works and I can view the plot in the `.pdf` file.

This makes absolutely no sense to me! It appears that running the `gnuplot` script and plotting to the screen fixes something in `foo.tex` and foo.eps AFTER they have been created. What is going on?

Comment: Can you post the error message please?

Comment: Do you really need `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`? With just `pdflatex paper` you should be OK.

Comment: Maybe you didn't do `unset out` (which finalizes and closes the output `.eps` file)? Switching the terminal in gnuplot might do that automatically.

Comment: egreg, I was experiencing the same problem with pdflatex.

Comment: Lars Kotthoff, I edited the question to include the error message.

Comment: @D_J_S Can you please add the gnuplot source file for experimentation? This might just be a ghostscript bug: what version are you using?

Comment: @Marijin. Placing an unset output like you suggested fixes the problem. Thanks!! But I have no idea why my "fix" worked? I even quit gnuplot before writing the plot to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that file maintains open by gnuplot waiting for data, if you need to use the file created you must close that file using set output command and then return the previous device using set term pop command

Comment: Thank you @user191086. A very convincing argument.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem (Thanks Marijn) is to include the following line at the end of the gnuplot script:

```
    unset output
```

However I do not understand how plotting to the screen would also fix the problem after the files foo.tex and foo.eps had already been written. That remains a mystery to me. Is GnuPlot setting a system variable that is used
by ps2pdf? Something is buggy.